# Why setup method that is annotated with BeforeAll doesn't save ShippingAddress object to DB?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to add some tests to my project and I need to populate the DB before running my tests.

I have tried to do it by using a void setup() method, annotated with BeforeEach and trying to make sure that data is not rolled back. Here is my code sample. I would have to add that both shippingAddressRepository and billingAddressRepository extend JPARepository. When I run test, it throws a custom exception that tells me that id for shipping address is not found in DB.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {OrdersApiApplication.class, H2JpaConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestClassOrder(ClassOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
class OrdersControllerTest extends GenericIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ShippingAddressRepository shippingAddressRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BillingAddressRepository billingAddressRepository;
    private static ShippingAddress testShippingAddress;
    private static BillingAddress testBillingAddress;

    @BeforeAll
    @Rollback(value=false)
    public void setup() {
        testShippingAddress = shippingAddressRepository.save(new ShippingAddress("1","0722123443","Popescu","Ana","aleea lalelelor", "Romania","Sv","2112",null));
        System.out.println(testShippingAddress);
        testBillingAddress = billingAddressRepository.save(new BillingAddress("1", "0722123443","Popescu","Ana","aleea lalelelor", "Romania","Sv","2112",null));
    }
    @Nested
    class CreateOrderTests {

        @Nested
        class CreateProductTests {
            private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            @Test
            void shouldCreateOrderSuccessfully() throws Exception {

                ShippingAddress shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
                shippingAddress.setId("1");
                // act
                MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc
                        .perform(createPostRequest(OrdersController.PATH, new CreateOrderReqDTO(OrderStatus.PAID, 3, 100.0, 100.0, 5.0, "1", "1", "1", "1")))
                        .andReturn();

                OrderDTO response = mapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), new TypeReference<>() {
                });

                // assert
                assertEquals(100.0, response.getTotal());
                assertEquals(100.0, response.getGrandTotal());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Try this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

- use liquibase scripts with test data for test environment
- use @Sql annotation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html
- If you use testcontainers like PostgreSQLContainer, there are method withInitScript("someScript.sql")
- If you use H2 then put to your url init part like : "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:scripts/create.sql'"